# Using Mod rewrite to change url paths as shown

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to achieve this,

My query is

```
domain.com/forum.php?id=100000
```

i want to rewrite that to

```
domain.com/forum/id/10000
```

i have tried to do this ,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+) 
RewriteRule ^forum.php /%1/? [R=301]
```

but i get it as

```
domain.com/10000.
```

if someone could help me solve this, i would really appretiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this-
If you url is like below

```
domain.com/forum/id/10000
```

Than rule will be

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$/([a-zA-Z]+)$/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ $1.php?$2=$3
```

Comment: How exactly do you think having multiple `$` inside a regular expression is going to work?

Comment: my question is to get the opposite done , from domain.com/forum.php?id=10000 to domain.com/forum/id/10000

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ forum.php?$1=$2
```

And go to

`http://domain.com/forum/id/10000`

You should now see the same output that you get when you go to

`http://domain.com/forum.php?id=10000`